# Phonegap with PHP backend header setup to restrict access

Tags: php, cordova

i am creating an app using phonegap and i am using php as a back-end.

I have access to both the server side and app code.i am using the following code so that i don't have CORS issue

```
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: *");
```

How do i set my php header values so that only my app can access it or at least make the php code suck so it's is not open for all.

Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PhoneGap has the options to define this in the config.xml file.

```
<access origin="http://google.com" />

<access origin="https://google.com" />

<access origin="http://*.google.com" />

<access origin="*" />
```

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.2.0/guide_appdev_whitelist_index.md.html#Whitelist%20Guide